# When executing a process with Multiprocessing Poolmap the process does not finish

Tags: python, multiprocessing

i am trying to use the Multiprocess module from python in order to make more efficient a code that I have but when I execute it, it is like it goes on a loop that never finishes.

This is the simple funciton I executed to see if it worked:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def prueba(n):
    return n*n

if __name__ == "__main__":
    m=[1,2,3,4,5]
    result=[]
    pool=Pool()
    result=pool.map(prueba,m)
    print(result)
```

Can someone tell me why this is happening? Thank you!

Comment: Your snippet works fine both in a standalone .py file and inside a notebook cell. What is you environment?

Comment: Hi! My environment is Spyder

Comment: Please [edit] to show how exactly you are running this code and what the output looks like in Spyder.